# Rolling Regression on python

Tags: python, regression, rolling-computation

I am trying to run rolling regression for several x_variable using the below code:

```
# Get data for specified date range
pred = pred[beg_date:end_date]

# Lag and standardize pred
pred[var_list_all] = pred[var_list_all].shift(1)
pred[var_list_all] = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(pred[var_list_all])

# Initialize dictionary of lists
d = {}
for i in ['coeff', 't-stat', 'r2']:
    d[i] = []

# Run bi-variate regression for each pred variable
y_var = 'EP'
for x_var in var_list_all:
    formula = y_var + ' ~ ' + x_var
    results = RollingOLS.from_formula(formula, window=60, data=pred)

    d['coeff'].append(results.params[x_var])
    d['t-stat'].append(results.params[x_var] / results.bse[x_var])
    d['r2'].append(results.rsquared * 100)
```

The aim is to collect the coefficient, t-stat and r2 for each variable and plot the r2 for each on separate graphs.

Whenever I am running the regression I keep on getting the following message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_locals'

I've also tried the example on https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/rolling_ls.html to see if I do understand what is going on, but I get the same error message.

I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Would appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The shift should create a None value in the first row of your dataframe. You need to remove it using dropna (). However, check for other null values before using isnull (). Regressions algorithms usualy don't handle null values.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I am still getting the same error after using dropna. I've gone through the data again, there's no null values.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example with RollingOLS from statsmodels. The inspiration is from the [answer to this question on Rolling OLS Regressions and Predictions by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119449/rolling-ols-regressions-and-predictions-by-group).

```py
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = sm.datasets.grunfeld.load()
df_grunfeld = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
df_grunfeld.set_index(['firm'], append=True, inplace=True)

# Simple Model
# $$invest = \beta_0 + \beta_1 value$$

def invest_params(df_gf, intercept=False):

    """
    Function to operate on the data of a single firm.
    Assumes df_gf has the columns 'invest' and 'value' available.
    Returns a dataframe containing model parameters
    """

    # we should have at least k + 1 observations
    min_obs = 3 if intercept else 2
    wndw = 8 

    # if there are less than min_obs rows in df_gf, RollingOLS will throw an error
    # Instead, handle this case separately

    if df_gf.shape[0] < min_obs:
        cols = ['coef_intercept', 'coef_value'] if intercept else ['coef_value']
        return pd.DataFrame(index=df_gf.index, columns=cols)

    y = df_gf['invest']
    x = add_constant(df_gf['value']) if intercept else df_gf['value']

    model = RollingOLS(y, x, expanding=True, min_nobs=min_obs, window=wndw).fit()

    parameters = model.params
    params_shifted = model.params.shift(1)
    mse = model.mse_resid
    parameters['invest_hat'] = (parameters.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat')

    parameters['invest_hat_shift'] = (params_shifted.mul(add_constant(df_gf['value']), axis=0)\
                                      .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)).to_frame('invest_hat_shift')

    parameters['mse'] = mse
    parameters['rmse'] = np.sqrt(mse)
    parameters['nobs'] = model.nobs
    parameters['ssr'] = model.ssr
    parameters['t_const'] = model.tvalues['const']
    parameters['t_value'] = model.tvalues['value']
    parameters.rename(columns = {'const' : 'b0', 'value' : 'b1'}, inplace = True)
    parameters['r2_adj'] = model.rsquared_adj
    
    return parameters

grouped = df_grunfeld.groupby('firm')
df_params = grouped.apply(lambda x: invest_params(x, True))
df_grunfeld_output = df_grunfeld.join(df_params, rsuffix='_coef')
```